# bitcoindの構築について

Tags: windows, cygwin

初級的な質問で申し訳ありません。
現在、windowsOSでブロックチェーンについて勉強しようと思っているのですが、[GitHubのビットコインページ](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)をクローニングした後の`autogen.sh`によるスクリプトの設定がうまくいきません。
Cygwinを用いて https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git をクローンして行っているのですが、`./configure`の実行後、以下のエラーが発生します。

1. wgetにより入れたBerkeley 4.830を解凍したが、Found Berkeley other than 4.8のwarningが発生する
2. makeの段階で

   ```
   chainparams.cpp:217:72: エラー: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned char>’ and ‘boost::assign_detail::generic_list<int>’)
        base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = list_of(0x04)(0x35)(0x87)(0xCF);
   ```

   および

   ```
   chainparams.cpp:218:72: エラー: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned char>’ and ‘boost::assign_detail::generic_list<int>’)
        base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = list_of(0x04)(0x35)(0x83)(0x94);
   ```

   というエラーが発生する

特に2で`make error`となるのでこれを最も解決したいと思っております。
プログラミング初歩者であるため、質問内容が煩雑となっているかもしれませんが、もし差し支えなければご指導いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 該当のGitHubリポジトリを提示してもらわないと、具体的な回答は難しいと思います。

Comment: 返信いただきありがとうございます。失礼いたしました。https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.gitです。

Comment: `autogen.sh`はシェルスクリプトなので、そのままではWindows上で動きません。単に`Windows`だけでなく、シェルスクリプトや`make`などLinuxコマンドが使える環境が整っているのかも確認してもらい、必要に応じて [編集] から本文に追記してみてください。

Comment: 返信いただきありがとうございます。すなわち、Linux環境を構築しないと動作させることができないという事でよろしいでしょうか。大変な初級者で申し訳ありません。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bitcoin/bitcoin の [Windows 用インストール・ドキュメント](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5f0c6a7b0e47e03f848dc992d37fe209dd9c6975/doc/build-windows.md)によると、2018年4月現在 Cygwin 上でのビルドはあまりテストされていないようです。

現在出力されているエラーも C++ コンパイラの環境まわりが原因に見えます。お使いの Windows が充分更新された Windows 10 ならば、ドキュメントに書かれている通り Windows Subsystem for Linux 上で Mingw-w64 を使ってクロスコンパイルする方法に切り替えるのはいかがですか？